# R - Customizing X Axis Values in Histogram

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I want to change the values on the x axis in my histogram in R.

The computer currently has it set as

```
0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100.
```

I want the x axis to go by 10 as in:

```
0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100.
```

I know to get rid of the current axis I have to do this

```
(hist(x), .... xaxt = 'n')
```

and then

```
axis(side = 1) .....
```

But how do I get it to show the numbers that I need it to show?

Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

The answer is right there in `?axis`...

```
dat <- sample(100, 1000, replace=TRUE)
hist(dat, xaxt='n')
axis(side=1, at=seq(0,100, 10), labels=seq(0,1000,100))
```

Comment: Looks like `xaxt` is now depricated in the call to `hist()`

Comment: @polyphant -- Hmm. That's odd. It still works just fine for me in R version 3.1.2 (though any explicit mention of it seems to have been removed from the documentation).

Comment: Just tried again to be sure and it now works (sorry..) but it has disappeared from the docs. You can call `axes=F` but this removes both axes.