# Difficulties setting the x-axis of a histogram in R to represent the true domain of the random variable

Tags: r, histogram

I just realized that in [this post I put together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46984446/4089351) the histogram has just index values on the x-axis, instead of the intended 0 to 5 range:

[image]

```
Here is the code for convenience:

x1 = 5           # Maximum value
x0 = 0.1         # It can't be zero; otherwise X^0^(neg) is 1/0.
alpha = -2.5     # It has to be negative.
y = runif(1e5)   # Number of samples
x = ((x1^(alpha+1) - x0^(alpha+1))*y + x0^(alpha+1))^(1/(alpha+1))

h = hist(x, prob=T, breaks=40, plot=F)
plot(h$count, log="xy", type='l', lwd=1, lend=2, 
xlab="", ylab="", main="Density in logarithmic scale")
```

Logically, I have search and found some pertinent posts, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8481666/4089351) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38995201/4089351), and have tried things like

```
x1 = 5           # Maximum value
x0 = 0.1         # It can't be zero; otherwise X^0^(neg) is 1/0.
alpha = -2.5     # It has to be negative.
y = runif(1e5)   # Number of samples
x = ((x1^(alpha+1) - x0^(alpha+1))*y + x0^(alpha+1))^(1/(alpha+1))

h = hist(x, prob=T, breaks=40, plot=F)
plot(h$count, log="xy", type='l', lwd=1, lend=2, 
xlab="", ylab="", xaxt = 'n', main="Density in logarithmic scale")
axis(side=1, at=seq(0, 5, .2), labels=seq(0, 5, .2))
```

getting non-sensical results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `density()`.

```
plot(density(x), log="y", ylab="log density x", col=2)
legend("topright", "x", lty=1, col=2)
```

[image]

*Note:* `set.seed(42)`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to produce a histogram with the same x axis?

Comment: @Toni I guess you mean the x axis should also be logarithmic?

Comment: No, that's fine, `log = "y"` or `log = "xy"`... I was asking about avoiding altogether the density function - although it is the best choice - and doing the same (discretized or binned) with hist().

Comment: @Toni I'm not sure about the benefits, `hist` calculates densities as well and the `lines` function smooths then over the bins? However, we probably should take more care of the `from`, `to`, `cut`etc. parameters of `density()`.